# Is there any way to use Swift for iOS as well as android development?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, publish

When having a finished iOS app, coded with Swift via Xcode, is there any way to use the code and in general the project file and kind of transfer it into Java, C or C++ code which that can be used to create an android app?

Learning an additional programming language, such as Java or C, "just" so I can publish two these two stores isn't hopefully the only solution to this kind of problem.

I´d appreciate any of your past experiences and ideas related to my problem.

Comment: Nope. You can either go with a cross-platform solution (Ionic, Xamarin, etc.), and accept the compromises inherent in those frameworks, or you can write them natively.

Answer (score 0):

You could have wrote it initially in React Native for example, or using Flutter or Xamarin or whatever framework you wanted to write once and then run on both iOS and Android.

If you want an app with GUI and not a simple HelloWorld, i don't think so, as far as I am aware there is no way to do it.

There is a possibility to **COMPILE a Swift code on Android**, of that I am sure, but to run an app out of the box without using some additional frameworks - nope.

Comment: Okay, is there any possibility to convert big chunks of the code or the main project file into AndroidStudio / an programming language which is compatible with Android, so I don't have to learn and re-write the whole code?